# Foreign key constraint violation in oracle

Tags: oracle

I was testing foreign key violation and came across below exception. Please suggest.
I created below objects in oracle db -

```
create table dept as select * from scott.dept;
create table emp as select * from scott.emp;
alter table dept add constraint dept_pk3 primary key(deptno);
alter table emp add constraint emp_pk3 primary key(empno);
alter table emp  add constraint emp_fk_dept foreign key (deptno) references dept(deptno);
```

I tried below update query it fails with error message -

```
update dept set deptno=deptno-6;

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02292: integrity constraint (ORA1.EMP_FK_DEPT) violated - child record found
```

But if I fire below query it works fine

```
update dept set deptno=deptno-10;
```

Any reason?

Comment: run 'select distinct deptno from emp` and show the output.

Answer (score 0):

The default data in Oracle's demo tables `emp` and `dept` contains department numbers that are multiples of 10, i.e. 10, 20, 30, 40.

Department 40 has no associated employee. Therefore, `update dept set deptno=deptno-10;` results in new numbers 0, 10, 20, 30 that still satisfy the foreign key constraint - though the employees are now in a different department. On the other hand, `update dept set deptno=deptno-6;` causes a violation, because the employes in 10,20,30 no longer have a corresponding department.